# Composer - how to ignore some map files?

Tags: php, magento, dictionary, composer-php, magento2

I'm using composer in my PHP project. There is a module which maps lots of files into to root directory. This includes files like `README.md` and `CHANGELOG.md` and the `generation autolod files` throws an error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                
Target ./README.md already exists (set extra.magento-force to override)
```

Is there a option to ignore a list of files from the mapping and don't use the override option?

Comment: Can you give more details about which module is adding which files? I suspect the module should comprehend that in its own .gitignore or composer.json. Please include the log.

Comment: Maybe try magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://magento-composer-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Customise%20Install%20Process/ -> Ignore certain files from install   -> but that documentation does not seem to apply for the standard magento 2 composer installer

Answer (score 12):

I works like this, for example if you want to prevent the pub/.htaccess from being overwritten.

Add this to the `composter.json`

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "magento-deploy-ignore": {
        "*": [
            "/pub/.htaccess"
        ]
    }
}
```

See here for more information: https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/doc/Deploy.md#prevent-single-files-from-deploy

Remark: On upgrading Magento versions (2.2.4 -> 2.2.5) such files still seem to be deleted, so you have to restore them from the VCS