# Exluding files from updating in composer.json

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I have a magento 2 deployment script with capistrano.
How to exclude files from replacing during composer create-project command?

Comment: When exactly does that happen? Did you modify any files in `vendor`?

Comment: files are setup/config/di.config.php and setup/config/application.config.php
I am overriding class that is run during setup upgrade phase. The new class skip AWS EFS mounted directory (pub/media) permission checking to speed up magento 2 deployment.

Comment: any idea???????

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your question, not to the comment section. I still don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to ignore files from being overidden in magento 2 deployment, we can use

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "magento-deploy-ignore": {
        "*": [
            "/setup/config/application.config.php",
            "/setup/config/di.config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

[Composer - how to ignore some map files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732893/composer-how-to-ignore-some-map-files)

Comment: Can you explain further how that answers your question?

Comment: magento 2 will not replace those file during deployment. i don't know the detail. it just works.